# Derivative of $\mbox{tr}\left\{ X^T A X^{-1} B\right\}$ w.r.t. matrix $X$ for a given $A$ and $B$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Dear Matrix Calculus Experts,

What is the derivative of $\mbox{tr}\left\{ X^T A X^{-1} B\right\}$ with respect to matrix $X$ for a given $A$ and $B$ matrices?

---

I came across http://www.matrixcalculus.org/, which can compute it for me (not sure either whether it is correct), i.e., 
\begin{align}  
\nabla_{X} \ \mbox{tr}\left\{ X^T A X^{-1} B\right\}  = AX^{-1}B - X^{-T}A^TXB^TX^{-T}.
\end{align}

However, I would be happy to know the derivation steps. Could you experts please help me how to derive this?

Thank you so much in advance,

Comment: How is your matrix derivative defined? Assuming that it boils down to the ordinary derivative in the case of $1\times1$ matrices, the result cannot be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we denote the trace/Frobenius product with a colon, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
then the function can be written as
$$\phi = X:AX^{-1}B$$
The differential of the matrix inverse can be calculated from first principles
$$\eqalign{
 I &= X^{-1}X \cr
 0 &= dX^{-1}\,X+X^{-1}\,dX \cr
 dX^{-1} &= -X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1} \cr
}$$
and this can be used to find the differential and gradient of the function
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= dX:AX^{-1}B + X:A\,dX^{-1}B \cr
 &= AX^{-1}B:dX - A^TXB^T:X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1} \cr
 &= \Big(AX^{-1}B - X^{-T}A^TXB^TX^{-T}\Big):dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &=
   AX^{-1}B - X^{-T}A^TXB^TX^{-T} \cr
}$$
This differs from the result you quoted in the sign of the second term.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry, there was a typo. So, apparently, it does match.